# Why is a range of function$ f(x) = x^2 $ always non-negative?

Tags: functions

And how do I find a range of any function?

Comment: That is only true if $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just because square of any real number is always non-negative. If domain of $x^2 \in\mathbb{C}$ then it could be negative number too.

Answer (score 2):

this is since $$x^2\geq 0$$ (the square of a real number is always non negative)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're working in the field of reals, one of the axioms of real numbers says:

> If $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a \geq b$ and $c>0$ then $ac \geq bc$

From here, it follows that $a^2 \geq 0$ $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1):

> And how do I find a range of any function?

There is no *general* method for this that will work for all functions. You just need to be clever and find something particular about the function definition you're looking at that you can exploit to find its range.

For example, here is a simple function $\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ where *nobody* knows its range:
$$ f(n) = \text{number of primes $p$ such that $2n+4-p$ is prime} $$
Nobody knows even whether $0$ is in the range -- that is the famous unsolved *Goldbach conjecture*.

Comment: what about common methods?